# Can't get radial gradient

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix, drawing, vector-graphics

I'm trying to create elipse with radial gradient fill, but flash makes it filled with solid color (the second one - 0xe9afaf)

```
var mat:Matrix = new Matrix();  
mat.createGradientBox(150, 100, 0, 0, 0);

timeField = new Shape();
timeField.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.RADIAL, [0xd35f57, 0xe9afaf], [1, 1], [0,255],mat);
timeField.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0x561717);
timeField.graphics.drawEllipse(GlobalVariables.globalStage.stageWidth / 2 - 75, -50, 150, 100);
timeField.graphics.endFill();

addChild(timeField);
```

I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of your matrix's gradient box and your ellipse are off center, so you're seeing the solid part of the gradient after all the color has faded out. You're going to have to offset your gradient box to match the position of the ellipse.

Line 2:
`mat.createGradientBox(150, 100, 0, GlobalVariables.globalStage.stageWidth / 2 - 75, -50);`

Or you can also make your ellipse at 0, 0 and move the timeField to the center where you want it.

`timeField.graphics.drawEllipse(0, 0, 150, 100);`

`timeField.x = GlobalVariables.globalStage.stageWidth / 2 - 75;`
`timeField.y = -50;`